# Como insertar datos en tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema con un proyecto. Espero me ayuden a resolverlo.

Quiero insertar datos a mi base de datos con repecto al formulario EJ:

En el formulario hay una opcion: Seccion,y quiero que si el usuario da click en la opcion "populares" los datos se guarden en una tabla ya establecida (populares) o si por ejemplo da click en la opcion "ultimaactualizacion" pues guarde los datos en una tabla distinta (ultimaactualizacion) y asi susesivamente.

Espero ser claro con mi pregunta. Gracias.

Este es el codigo del formulario:

```
<form action="db_apk.php" method="post">
      <label class="">Nombre del APK:</label>
      <input class="" name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Ejemplo" required >
      <label class="">Nombre del paquete:</label>
      <input class="" name="namepackage" type="number" id="namepackage" placeholder="exaple.com.co" required >
      <label class="">Sección:</label>
      <select  class="" name="seccion" id="seccion" required>
          <option value="populares">Populares</option>
          <option value="ultimasactualizaciones">Ultimas Actualizaciónes</option>
          <option value="nuevoslanzamientos">Nuevos Lanzamientos</option>
          <option value="gratis">Gratis</option>
      </select>
      <label class="">Categoría:</label>
      <select  class="" name="category" id="category" required>
          <option value="accion">Acción</option>
          <option value="aventura">Aventura</option>
          <option value="deporte">Deporte</option>
          <option value="arcade">Arcade</option>
      </select>
      <label class="">Tamaño del APK:</label>
      <input class="" name="tamapk" type="text" id="tamapk" required >
      <label class="">Valoración:</label>
      <input class="" name="rating" type="number" id="rating" required >
      <label class="">Numero de descargas:</label>
      <input class="" name="numberdowloads" type="text" id="numberdowloads" required >
      <label class="">Icono:</label>
      <input class="" name="icon" type="file" id="icon" required >
      <button type="submit">Subir</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se define en el archivo `db_apk.php`. ¿Qué tienes escrito en él? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Eso lo puedes definir (action="db_apk.php") directamente en el backend con condicionales.
Pero lo que si te tiene que quedar claro es que es en el backend no importa el formulario.